# display different template based on post type

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

Hay, i have a custom post type "Events", however this is basically a post type, so it inherits the post.php template page.

Is there anyway to use a different template (i.e events.php) if the content type is an 'event'?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `single-events.php`.

See [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) in Codex for full scheme of templates.

Comment: Works a charm, I'm only getting used to how WordPress works, i honestly didn't know it was this flexible!

Comment: Yep, templates are extremely flexible system. Just be aware that some frameworks (like Hybrid) apply their own template hierarchy, defaults are not set in stone.

Answer (score 1):

This is why using the custom template files that you can use like page-{post_type}.php and single-{post_type}.php are extremely handy. And in 3,1, archive-{post_type}.php too.

So yea, you just create a template file for your post types, using the custom templates like that instead of the way where you put the template name in a comment at the top of the file. That way sucks, and I never ever use it, and I create post types like maddness.

Comment: I read about `single-{post_type}.php` and `archive-{post_type}.php` in codex. Couldn't find a reference for `page-{post_type}.php` Are you sure about this? Can you share some reference?

Comment: It's part of page templates. Read about the template hierarchy here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy