# How to create custom post type like Page

Tags: custom-post-types, multi-language

I want to create a Custom Post Type like Post or Page, It should have Page templates Option. This is for multilingual site. Any comments on this ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) page in the codex. Look at the `hierarchical` argument when registering your post type

> **hierarchical**
>   (boolean) (optional)
>
> Whether the post type is hierarchical (e.g. page). Allows Parent to be specified. The 'supports' parameter should contain 'page-attributes' to show the parent select box on the editor page.
>
> Default: *false*

Answer (score 0):

No, by default you can not add support for templates to custom post types. But there are some plugins that allow this functionality.

You can use [Custom Post Template](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-template/) or [Single Post Template Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/single-post-template/) plugin to add template support for single posts which includes custom post types too.

You can read more about it here.
[Can I assign a template to a custom post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23674/can-i-assign-a-template-to-a-custom-post-type)

It's already been discussed. In this topic, there are some other ways but will not work for individual post. Although you can set a template for post type.

Answer (score 0):

*Custom Post Type Templates*

archive-{post_type}.php
single-{post_type}.php

**archive-{post_type}.php** 
If your custom post type were 'product', and/or query_var = "product", WordPress would look for archive-product.php to display the archive of posts.

**single-{post_type}.php** 
If your custom post type were 'product', and/or query_var = "product", WordPress would look for single-product.php to display the single or permalink of the post.

If these files are not available in your Theme's directory WordPress will look for archive.php and single.php, respectively. If even these files are not present it will default to index.php. See Template Hierarchy for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> Create Custom Post Type Create post type page

```
$page = get_page_by_path('buyer-order-request');
if (!$page) {
    $buyer_order_requ= '[buyer_order_request]';
    $post = array(
          'comment_status' => 'closed',
          'ping_status' =>  'closed' ,
          'post_author' => 1,
          'post_content' => $buyer_order_requ,
          'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
          'post_name' => 'buyer-order-request',
          'post_status' => 'publish' ,
          'post_title' => 'Buyer Order Request',
          'post_type' => 'page',
    );  
    //insert page and save the id
    $newvalue = wp_insert_post( $post, false );
    //save the id in the database
    update_option( 'buyerorder_page', $newvalue );
  }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as how it answers OP

Comment: "buyer-order-request"  is a page name if (!$page) check condition if return true than create a new page
 $buyer_order_requ= '[buyer_order_request]';
'[buyer_order_request]' is a shortcode of content for by default display content on page
"post_title" is a title of page