# Dynamic assign a custom template to custom post type posts

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, page-template

So I am writing a plugin and I am wanting to assign a custom template that exist within my plugin directory to a registered CPT (features).
I have cpt-features-template.php as the file name located in my plugin folder root.

Can I do something like:

```
add_filter('single_template', function($original){
  global $post;
  //$post_name = $post->post_name;
  $post_type = $post->post_type;
  $base_name = 'custom-' . $post_type . '-template.php';
  $template = locate_template($base_name);
  if ($template && ! empty($template)) return $template;
  return $original;
});
```

Above code referenced from [Can I assign a template to a custom post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23674/can-i-assign-a-template-to-a-custom-post-type)

Comment: the file `cpt-features-template.php` is in your plugin directory ?

Comment: @mmm yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`locate_template` search template only in themes then to use a file outside themes, you can use the filter `template_include` like that

```
add_filter("template_include", function ($template) {


    $post = get_queried_object();

    if (    is_single()
        &&  ("features" === $post->post_type)
    ) {
        // absolute path to the template file
        $template = __DIR__ . "/../../template/my_features_template.php";
    }


    return $template;

});
```