# Assigning alternate single-{cpt} template based on blog_id in multisite

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite, templates, hooks

I have a multisite network with some shared custom post types, and I'm trying to create a function that loads a custom `single-{cpt}` template for a given post type by `$blog_id` when defined, and otherwise fall-back to the default `single-` template. In this case, the custom post type is `resource`, which would default to `single-resource.php` and I'm setting a variable `$custom_resource_single` to the applicable template file name as follows:

```
if ($blog_id == 5) {
   $custom_resource_single = 'single-resource-alt.php';
}
```

I'm then trying to pass this variable to a function used as a callback in the `template_include` filter hook as follows (adapting somewhat from [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23674/can-i-assign-a-template-to-a-custom-post-type)), but it's not working:

```
function custom_resource_single($custom_resource_single, $template) {
    if ( is_singular('resource') && !empty($custom_resource_single) ) {
        $custom = locate_template($custom_resource_single);
        return $custom;
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', function() use ($custom_resource_single, $template) { custom_resource_single($custom_resource_single, $template); });
```

I attempting to use a closure based on some other threads I've found here, but I'm clearly not using it properly. I can successfully achieve the result by passing an anonymous function with the `$blog_id` conditional directly to `template_include` hook, but I'd really like to be able to pass a variable (`$custom_resource_single`) to the function that is defined elsewhere.

Please let me know if my aim as described above is unclear, and thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: "*defined elsewhere*" - but in the same scope as the *closure*? If so, you might be looking at passing variables by reference: `use ( &$custom_resource_single )` ? But why don't you run the conditional from within the `template_include` filter - e.g. `if ( 5 == get_current_blog_id() ) $template = 'single-resource-alt.php';` ?

Comment: @SallyCJ I've created a lib file called `multisite-functions.php` in which I've set up a bunch of options grouped by `$blod_id` to try to keep everything organized, so my hope is to to set the `$custom_resource_single` variable by `$blog_id` and then pass that variable to the function I described above, if that makes sense- I could do what you're suggesting, but I'd like to keep the conditional out of the filter function itself. I've been able to do so for other things like enabling custom post types, taxonomies, etc. but can't get it working for the single- template

Comment: I've just posted an answer. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I noticed that your closure is not capturing/using the proper `$template` variable which is passed from the `template_include` filter hook:

```
// This hook is defined in wp-includes/template-loader.php
$template = apply_filters( 'template_include', $template )
```

*The closure is also not returning the template..*

So your closure should look like:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) use ( $custom_resource_single ) {
    return custom_resource_single( $custom_resource_single, $template );
} );
```

But you may want to pass the `$custom_resource_single` by reference (`use ( &$custom_resource_single )`) in case it gets changed *after* the above closure:

```
if ( $blog_id == 5 ) {
    $custom_resource_single = 'single-resource-alt.php';
}

add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) use ( &$custom_resource_single ) {
    return custom_resource_single( $custom_resource_single, $template );
} );

// $custom_resource_single is changed here.
if ( /* condition */ ) {
    $custom_resource_single = 'file.php';
}
```

Comment: Thank you- this is working great! Question just from a learning standpoint- you're saying I could pass the variable by reference in the event that I might want to change it later? (Whereas just using `$custom_resource_single` would not allow it to be changed later?)

Comment: You're very welcome. :) And yes to the first question in your comment. But regarding the second question, let me answer it like this: When you pass a variable by reference (instead of by value, which is the default behavior in PHP), you can "listen" to the variable when its value gets changed outside of the closure, and secondly, you can also change the value from within the closure. Try [this simple example/demonstration](https://pastebin.com/beFt8wfd) and check also [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) on php.net. I hope that helps. :)

Comment: Interesting, ok- thanks much for the explanation; that makes sense. I'll check out those links you provided!

Comment: Sure, take your time! (PS: Sorry about the "in your comment".. that just sounds funny, lol..)